# Database schema for multiple choice Trivia game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to determine the most efficient db schema for a multiple choice trivia game. I have the questions and answers in a spreadsheet with the columns, **'question_id', 'level', 'question', 'wrong_ans1', 'wrong_ans2', 'wrong_ans3', 'correct_ans'.**

Should I break the data into multiple tables **'questions'** with columns such as **(id, question, level, is_active)** and **'question_choices'** with columns such as **(id, choice, is_correct,)**?

I have a table called **'user_ans'** so I can keep track of the question a user has played and the answer they've given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either:

1. Keep answers in a single table with a boolean to indicate the correct answer, just as you describe.
   or ...
2. Keep answers in a single table, and use an attribute on the question model to identify the correct answer's id. This ensures that only one answer is correct.

In the latter case:

```
Question
  attr_accessible :question, :level, correct_answer_id
  has_many :answers     , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :user_answers, :through   => :answers

Answer
  attr_accessible :answer, :question_id
  belongs_to :question
  has_many   :user_answers, :dependent => :destroy

User_Answer
  attr_accessible :user_id, :answer_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
```

Over-thinking this a bit, if you had a lot of questions that had the same sets of answers but with a different ones being correct for different questions, then you could bundle up answers into sets ("Blue", "Green", "Red") and link questions to sets -- in that case you'd certainly have to indicate the correct answer at the question level.

Comment: Hi David, Each question will have different multiple choice answers. Can you show how the models would look, including the User_ans? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

a question model

```
Question
   attr_accessible :question, :level
   has_many wrong_answers
   has_one correct_answer

Wrong_answer
   attr_accessible :answer, :question_id
   belongs_to :question

Correct_answer
   attr_accessible :answer, :question_id
   belongs_to :question
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, how do you see the User_Ans model configured?